# текст не влезает в кнопки и в меню команд python aiogram

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telegram, aiogram

У меня есть бот для телеграмма на aiogram, в боте есть кнопки и меню команд, но текст, который я использую не влезает и сокращается. При чем на iphone текст не сокращается, а переносится, а на android обрезается. Как это можно исправить?

Comment: Прикрепите скриншот пожалуйста, но мне кажется это не решаемая проблема, т.к. за перенос текста отвечает клиентовская сторона

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`resize_keyboard = True` - задано при вызове `ReplyKeyboardMarkup`.